# New to Android, How can I edit my Relative Layout using Java?

Tags: java, android-layout

I have defined my Relative Layout using the drag and drop tool in Eclipse, so all of my buttons are laid out how I wish. My issue is when I set the onClick listener, that calls a method in another class. So to be able to redraw items on screen, I need to access the layout manager so I can add and remove buttons from the screen as well as update textViews. I have done all of this in a demo I made in Java, and I used a JPanel with GridBagConstraints. Now that I am moving to Android, a system I haven't done much development in, I am at the point where I have to learn some new stuff. For example in my demo I made I could do this:

```
grid.remove(trueButton);
grid.add(falseButton);
grid.remove(textField);
grid.add(backButton);
```

Essentially I want to be able to do the same sort of thing in my Android app. If you guys need more info I can provide, I wasn't really sure how much would be needed since I am looking at really just where to start. Everything has been declared in the XML since the drag and drop part of Eclipse does that all for me. It is just the Java part that is giving me some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setVisibility of the buttons you wish to hide/show? Same with the TextViews.

You can set visibility to 'GONE' and it will be as if the view has been removed (taking up no space in the layout and not responding to touch events.).

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think of that. And all I would have to do then is to define the button in Java like: 'Button btw = new Button()' (I know that isn't right, just an example) thus allowing me later on in my method call to say btw.setVisibility(GONE).